# How can I click on a submit button that is blocked by an 'onclick' submit handler's 'disabled' attribute on a website using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript-debugger

[fidelity login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2nhR.jpg)I used to be able to login to my fidelity account at https://nb.fidelity.com/public/nb/default/home and scrape certain data, but now I can't login via scripts anymore.
I am using firefox javascript debugger on my selenium data scraping script to debug why it is blocked on a login submit.
Seems like the onclick submit handler of the fidelity website is setting attribute disabled to disable. Submit works in manual mode but not through selenium. Need help with some strategies to login. I am not sure why its getting disabled on click when it works manually. It used to work until fidelity made some code changes. I think finding and modifying the submit handler through selenium to undo the disable code, so I can click on submit and login is the way to go. Any ideas appreciated.

I tried to clear the disabled attribute on the submit button through selenium which succeeded, but upon clicking it , the submit handler disabled the button again. I tried to find the submit handler by breakpoint on click, but it goes into a lot of gory code that I pretty printed, but it's hard to track, let alone change.

[login page under javascript debugger after clicking submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PEXB.jpg)

Comment: Please give as the site URL, or copy the HTML and show us where the element you are trying to click on is located

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.